# Fill column with last known value after pandas df.stack

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack

I am trying to figure out how i fill the blank spaces between dates after I stack my dataframe. I want each stock ticker to have the respective date rather than it only being reflected once per date. Thank you for any help.

```
import pandas as pd
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
positions_held = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'AMZN','SPOT']

yahoo_financials = YahooFinancials(positions_held)

data = yahoo_financials.get_historical_price_data(start_date='2020-12-28',
                                                  end_date='2021-12-31',
                                                  time_interval='daily')

df = pd.DataFrame({
    a: {x['formatted_date']: x['adjclose'] for x in data[a]['prices']} for a in positions_held
})

df = df.stack(dropna=True)

df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the most flexible dataframe

```
df = df.unstack(level=-1)
```

will give you

```
            MSFT        AAPL        AMZN        SPOT
2020-12-28  224.960007  136.690002  3283.959961 317.290009
2020-12-29  224.149994  134.869995  3322.000000 318.429993
2020-12-30  221.679993  133.720001  3285.850098 319.350006
```

Comment: thanks but I specifically want the data arranged vertically, that's why I stacked it in the first place